# Angular app production version don't work correctly

Tags: angular, deployment, production

I have Angular app on localhost and it works correct (ng serve), but when I deploy it to production version (ng build --prod) and install this on my apache server app doesn't work correctly. Components aren't displayed or displayed under page. When I change window size of my browser component appears or appears in the correct place.
You can see this in my video: https://youtu.be/KiibUNATc88

Command ng build don't show any errors. Only this [warrings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSCPh.png) but it shows also when I using ng serve.

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Comment: just inspect your css rules and see what's wrong! the details you shared doesn't help identify the issue (at least for me)

Comment: Hey Lukaz_7 do you have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> in your index.html.
Also are you using a package for the calendar?

Comment: Yes I have the same tag meta. I using a package FullCalenadar for the calendar.

Comment: It could be something with fxFlex? Because when I delete this from code the composition looks like on production version, but when I change for example widnow size the position doesn't change.